# php - Handle application/x-www-form-urlencoded POST request using php

Tags: php, json, content-type, urlencode, urldecode

I am trying to handle `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` POST request using PHP. Clients send a request in the format below:

```
POST /index.php User-Agent: Android/4.0 
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept-Encoding: gzip
action=Settings&device_id=2112121&app_version=420
```

And server's response must be like the following:

```
{
    "action": "Settings",
    "data": {
        "entries": {
            "service_enabled": "true"
        }
    },
    "data_format": "json"
}
```

Have any ideas for `index.php` on the server side?

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far, and we'll help you fix any problems you've come across.

Comment: No, I have no idea. Where is the `"data"` coming from? What should we do with `device_id=2112121&app_version=420`?

Answer (score -4):

Try this `$_POST  = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);`

Comment: This neither generates a response (as the OP suggested was the assignment) nor invents the extra data in his example.